# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
def multiple_dfs(file_name, sheet, *args):
    """
    Put multiple dataframes into one xlsx sheet
    """

    row=2
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')

    df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
               'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [100, 500, 1000], 
               'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)
    row += 2
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=0, startcol=0, header=None, \
             index=False)
```

I have the following error `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`, but I can't say what is the problem. Any suggestions?

I want to put a title at the top of a worksheet, but I don't know if it is the best practice. Could anyone be able to suggest me something with pandas?

Comment: Problem is `df2 = pd.DataFrame('Test')` - do you need `df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Test'])` ?

Answer (score 6):

It seems you need `list`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Test'])
print (df2)
      0
0  Test
```

EDIT:

It seems you need:

```
def multiple_dfs(file_name, sheet, *args):
    """
    Put multiple dataframes into one xlsx sheet
    """

    row=2
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
               'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'amount': [100, 500, 1000], 
               'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)
    row += len(df) + 1
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=0, startcol=0, header=None, \
             index=False)

multiple_dfs('file.xlsx','Sheet1')
```

Comment: Really hard question, because I have no your data. Also I cannot test `send_request` :(

Comment: OK, so can you change your question with multiple `dfs` for testing? Because I have no data and dont know desired output. Check  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I see you r modify answer, but how I can test offsets? I need 3-4 dataframes as input to function. thanks.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately without multiple dataframes and desired outpyut is it not possible, also `row` is unknown variable.

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea what is number of columns, rows, what is desired output. So I need your sample data, sorry :( Try to imagine you want answer only with information in question - I think it is not possible. I can guessing, but always better is nice sample data with desired output.

Comment: Thanks, I try `print (multiple_dfs('file.xlsx','aaa'))` and return errors :(

Comment: I never do it with `openpyxl` :(

Comment: Don't worry, I just ask ;)

Comment: Do you need `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')`? Because for me it does not work, only working `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name)` :( Maybe because windows? I have no idea.

Comment: Remove it, it is not a big deal

Comment: You forget for desire output, so I guess a bit and modify answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same error. My code worked fine on my computer which was like this:

```
test_dict = {'x': '123', 'y': '456', 'z': '456'}
df=pd.DataFrame(test_dict.items(),columns=['col1','col2'])
```

However, it did not work on another platform. which gave me the error `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` just like the original question.

I tried below code by simply adding the `list()` around the dictionary item,

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(test_dict.items()),columns=['col1','col2'])
```

and it worked smoothly!

Hopefully, this answer can help whoever ran into a similar situation like me.